# Saving workbook with text in cell as the name

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I have come up with. I get a compile error:

> object required.

```
Dim strName As String
Set wbk = "C:\Users\I53014\Desktop\Import_Creator.xlsm"
strName = wbk.Sheet1.Range("B2")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strName
```

I need to take the text that is in "Import_Creator.xlsm" sheet1 cell b2 and use it to save another workbook as that name.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming wbk is a Workbook object,

```
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\I53014\Desktop\Import_Creator.xlsm")
```

currently you are attempting to set this object to a string.

The book also has to be opened (even if temporarily) as the `Workbooks` collection only refers to open workbooks.

If possible, have a linked formula that refers to B2 in the other workbook, which will save you having to open and close it.

**Added** If the workbook is open then you could use

```
Set wbk = Workbooks("Import_Creator.xlsm")
```

If this book contains the code *that is currently running* then:

```
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
```

Just out of interest (for anyone reading) it is possible to get a value from a workbook without having to open and close it:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "='F:\Documents and Settings\student\My Documents\[AndysData7.xlsx]Staff List'!$D$6"
MsgBox Range("A1").Value
Range("A1").Clear
```

It is even possible to get this value without using a cell to enter the formula:

```
Debug.Print ExecuteExcel4Macro("'F:\Documents and Settings\student\My Documents\[AndysData7.xlsx]Staff List'!R6C4")
```

(thanks to a colleague of mine, Hans)

Comment: Andy, The workbook is open, it is where the macro starts from.

Comment: What can't you get to work? What errors do you receive? Add your updated code to your original question. Add it at the bottom - don't remove or alter your original question as it will confuse someone new reading this thread.

Comment: 'Dim strName As String
     Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

     strName = wbk.Range("B2")
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strName'  This is the code I have in there now and it tells me Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Yes, a `Range` doesn't apply to a `Workbook` object, it applies to a `Worksheet`. Insert `Sheet1` like you have in your original code, or `wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value`