# Opening and Excel file in Access using VBA and saving it to a different name and closing it properly

Tags: vba, excel-2010, ms-access-2010

I have been searching for some time on how exactly to go about this, but I keep coming up with a large number of possible ways that come close, but never really give me exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for.  The concept is pretty simple I need to open a certian .xls file using some VBA code in Access 2010.  Once the file is opened I need to insert data and do some things to the file then save the file as a different filename and close the file. I also need it to close excel if it was not already open and if it was open I need it to leave excel alone and not save/close anything other than the template.xls file I am working with. I currently have code that will do part of this provided Excel is not already open at the time the script runs.  When excel is already opened I get the following error;

*"Run-time'91':  Object variable or With block variable not set."*

When I click debug I get the following line highlighted

*x.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=savedfilename*

Here is the code without all the junk that doesn't relate to the issue. I have cobbled together using examples from various sites.

```
    Dim DateSampled As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim TemplatePath As String
    Dim x As Excel.Application
    Dim xBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    DateAsString = Format(DateSampled, "MMDDYYYY")
    savedfilename = strPath & "\" & TrainNum & "-" & DateAsString & ".xls"
    TemplatePath = "B:\template.xls"

    Set x = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    x.Visible = False
    Set xBook = GetObject(TemplatePath)
    xBook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    Set xSheet = xBook.Worksheets(1)

    '---------------CODE DOES STUFF WITH THE FILE -----------------------

    x.DisplayAlerts = False
    x.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=savedfilename
    x.DisplayAlerts = True
    x.ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Set x = Nothing
    Set xBook = Nothing
    Set xSheet = Nothing
```

Comment: replace `Set xBook = GetObject(TemplatePath)` with `Set xBook = x.Workbooks.Open(TemplatePath)`

Comment: @simoco Post this as an answer

Comment: @Tarik find the duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need VBA code for saving workbook with text in cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888046/need-vba-code-for-saving-workbook-with-text-in-cell)

Comment: As a matter of consistency, you should be doing `xBook.SaveAs ...` and `xBook.Close`.  This is better than `x.ActiveWorkbook` since you have already instantiated `xBook` to represent the specified file (whether it is active or not doesn't matter).  Also, do `x.Quit` to make sure you're releasing the Excel application.  Cheers.

Comment: @ckuhn203 Bravo! You found the duplicate!